# IdentityServer4: Set expiration date to "idsrv.session" cookie

Tags: identityserver4, asp.net-core-identity, asp.net-core-authenticationhandler

I get problems with the silent-refresh mechanism of my angular app, because the cookie expiration will not set correctly by the identity server.

After a successful login, the following cookies will be set for the domain of the identity server:
[image: 2020-08-20 12_53_39-ORF Zuul - Microsoft Visual Studio]

As you can see on the picture, the "idsrv.session" cookie has the expiration "session". In my old IdentityServer3 this cookie has a correct expiration date and all works fine.

Could anyone help me, to solve this problem. I need a way to set a expiration-date for the "idsrv.session" cookie.

**Here are the current configuration/statements, which I added to achieve my goal:**

```cs
// Startup.cs - ConfigureServices()
services
   .AddIdentityServer(options =>
   {
      options.EmitStaticAudienceClaim = true;
      options.AccessTokenJwtType = "JWT";
      options.Authentication.CookieLifetime = TimeSpan.FromDays(30);
   })
services
   .AddAuthentication("Cookies")
   .AddCookie("Cookies", options =>
   {
      options.ExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromDays(30);
   })
```

```cs
// AccountController.cs - Login()
await HttpContext.SignInAsync(isuser, new AuthenticationProperties
   {
       IsPersistent = true,
       ExpiresUtc = DateTimeOffset.UtcNow.Add(TimeSpan.FromDays(30))
    });
```

But this settings has no effekt on the "idsrv.session" cookie.

I use .net core 3.1 and IdentityServer4 4.0.4.

Thanks!!

**SOLUTION:**

In my case the following statement helps me, that a user will not logout after 30 minutes. The expiration "idsrv.session" cookie is although still set to session, but it will not removed after 30 minutes.

```cs
services.Configure<SecurityStampValidatorOptions>(o => o.ValidationInterval = TimeSpan.FromDays(30));
```

Comment: Is there a specific place (before / after) in Startup.cs file that I should be adding this? I tried adding this but seems like I check after 30 sec and idsrv.session cookie is not found or does not sustain.